# How to update 2 tables without a join and without using a loop

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have 2 tables, one contains people and one contains vouchers, i need to assign a voucher to each person and update the voucher table with the id of the person it was assigned to. Since there are no common keys to join the tables i can't use a recursive CTE, and i'd always try to avoid using a loop but i can't think fo any other way.

Is there anyway to do without using a loop? ideally in a single statement.

This will give an example of the tables (I am using SQL Server 2008 R2)

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), 
                      FirstName VARCHAR(30), 
                      LastName  VARCHAR(50),      
                      Voucher CHAR(5))

CREATE TABLE Vouchers (Voucher CHAR(5), 
                       Assigned INT)

INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName,LastName) VALUES ('Rob','Smith')
INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName,LastName) VALUES ('Alan','Brown')
INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName,LastName) VALUES ('John','Plant')
INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName,LastName) VALUES ('Mike','Black')
INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName,LastName) VALUES ('Steve','Green')

INSERT INTO Vouchers (Voucher) VALUES ('FEWPN')
INSERT INTO Vouchers (Voucher) VALUES ('ROPIW')
INSERT INTO Vouchers (Voucher) VALUES ('NGLCE')
INSERT INTO Vouchers (Voucher) VALUES ('WEKFE')
INSERT INTO Vouchers (Voucher) VALUES ('POIAP')
```

Comment: So how do you know who got which voucher?

Comment: What do you mean "can't use a recursive CTE"? Can you use a CTE at all? What is the reason for this limitation?

Comment: Also why do you need to update both tables? Do you really need the relationship to point in both directions? Why?

Comment: pondlife  - the assigned column on vouchers will be the id of the person it was assigned to.

Comment: Aaron - I can't see how i can use a CTE if i can;t join the tables, unless you know of a way i can. The requirements from the customer are that we have a record of which voucher was assigned to which person, so it made sense to use the voucher table rather than having a extra table to log it. Also the fact that an ID has been assigned indicates that the voucher has been used and cannot be used again.

Comment: Ok but I still don't understand what purpose the voucher column serves in the Persons table. You can find out what voucher they got (if any) by joining to the Vouchers table on p.ID = v.Assigned! You don't have to update both tables... this is quite redundant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that your data in order of how you want it

```
DECLARE @Persons TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), 
                      FirstName VARCHAR(30), 
                      LastName  VARCHAR(50),      
                      Voucher CHAR(5))

DECLARE @Vouchers TABLE (Voucher CHAR(5), 
                       Assigned INT)

INSERT INTO @Vouchers (Voucher)
    SELECT Voucher
    FROM
        (
        INSERT INTO @Persons (FirstName,LastName,Voucher)
        OUTPUT INSERTED.Voucher
        VALUES ('Rob','Smith', 'FEWPN'), ('Alan','Brown', 'FEWPN'), ('John','Plant', 'NGLCE'), ('Mike','Black', 'WEKFE'),('Steve','Green', 'POIAP')
        ) X   

SELECT * FROM @Persons P
SELECT * FROM @Vouchers V
```

Answer (score 5):

This uses a CTE (not a recursive one) and assumes that you don't care which voucher is assigned to which person. Each person will only have one `rn` and so will each voucher.

```
;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT ID, Voucher, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) FROM dbo.Persons
),
y AS 
(
  SELECT Voucher, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Voucher) FROM dbo.Vouchers
)
UPDATE x SET Voucher = y.Voucher
  FROM x INNER JOIN y
  ON x.rn = y.rn;

UPDATE v SET Assigned = p.ID
  FROM dbo.Vouchers AS v
  INNER JOIN dbo.Persons AS p
  ON v.Voucher = p.Voucher;
```